# Guideline Request: Posting personal/identifiable information

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, community

There's been some discussion in the comments of a recent MESE question, concerning what posted information might constitute a FERPA (or other privacy-act) violation. Does Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange have any advice along these lines so users

1. Steer clear of posting something inappropriate?
2. Have confidence that they're safe in making their post?

I know the SE network is not a legal firm, but having some folks look into this may be of help to the community at large.

Comment: I did not link to the particular recent question, as I'm not interested in discussing it as the only (potential) case of this issue, and because this is not at all meant as a "call out". Lest the conversation go that way, let me say that I'm looking for what advice the network has to help its users do the right thing.

Comment: Surely part of being an international forum is not being beholden to the rather absurd at times rules which fall under FERPA. This is a United States thing. For example, I was told I should not hand back homework in a certain way. Anyway, certainly names should be redacted unless permission was given and/or it was already a public matter. FERPA is so much more than that common sense.